# How to detect a out going phone call is received in android

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager, phone-call

I tried lot a get a solution and i need to detect when phone call is answered or rejected, any suggestion will help me lot. I have tried to detect using Boolean value. Please help me to get a solution.

My code:

```
public class CallerToActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {
    // static boolean wasRinging;
    static boolean finish = false;
    static Context mcontext;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        PhoneStateChangeListener pscl = new PhoneStateChangeListener();
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tm.listen(pscl, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        mcontext=context;
    }

    private static class PhoneStateChangeListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        static boolean wasRinging;

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                Log.i("Status", "RINGING");
                wasRinging = true;
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                Log.i("Status", "OFFHOOK");

                if (wasRinging == false) {
                    // Start your new activity

                } else {
                    // Cancel your old activity
                }

                // this should be the last piece of code before the break
                wasRinging = true;
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                Log.i("Status", "IDLE");
                // this should be the last piece of code before the break
                wasRinging = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I am using to do this:

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>

<!--This part is inside the application-->
    <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

My phone call detector

```
package com.xyz.android.reusable.receivers;

import java.util.Date;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public abstract class PhonecallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    //The receiver will be recreated whenever android feels like it.  We need a static variable to remember data between instantiations

    private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    private static Date callStartTime;
    private static boolean isIncoming;
    private static String savedNumber;  //because the passed incoming is only valid in ringing


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //We listen to two intents.  The new outgoing call only tells us of an outgoing call.  We use it to get the number.
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
            savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
        }
        else{
            String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            int state = 0;
            if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
            }


            onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
        }
    }

    //Derived classes should override these to respond to specific events of interest
    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}
    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}
    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}
    protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}

    //Deals with actual events

    //Incoming call-  goes from IDLE to RINGING when it rings, to OFFHOOK when it's answered, to IDLE when its hung up
    //Outgoing call-  goes from IDLE to OFFHOOK when it dials out, to IDLE when hung up
    public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
        if(lastState == state){
            //No change, debounce extras
            return;
        }
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                isIncoming = true;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                savedNumber = number;
                onIncomingCallStarted(context, number, callStartTime);
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
                if(lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    isIncoming = false;
                    callStartTime = new Date();
                    onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);                     
                }
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
                if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                    onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                }
                else if(isIncoming){
                    onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());                       
                }
                else{
                    onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());                                               
                }
                break;
        }
        lastState = state;
    }
}
```

Then to use it, simply derive a class from it and implement a few easy functions, whichever call types you care about:

```
public class CallReceiver extends PhonecallReceiver {

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Call from:" + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it working for you..? Sorry coz i tried every code so asking if it is working. It will save my life:)

Comment: onOutgoingCallStarted means it is ringing state or call active state..?

Comment: Where should i start my activity when out going call recived

Comment: means i need to start activity in CallReceiver right..?

Comment: I started my activity in  @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
    }  but it is starting ringing only

Comment: You need to create your own activity that extends `PhonecallReceiver` and use the methods you wish to use.

Comment: I am not getting pls can u update the above code. Just mention start your activity lable

Comment: See, the functions listed in `CallReceiver` are the functions in which you want to do anything. It could be simply just a Toast message in each of the functions. The actual work is done by `PhonecallReceiver`. It calls one of these functions according to whatever happens related to a phone call.

Comment: I've also shown the usage in `onIncomingCallStarted` by displaying a toast messge.

Comment: Incoming is working fine no prob but what i am asking is where should i put my start activity code..? for outgoing call. In CallReceiver  onOutgoingCallStarted OR PhonecallReceiver    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:..?

Comment: Because app is starting from ringing state so

Comment: Please put //Start activity line in above code to start my activity

Comment: In manifest for activity i given to LAUNCHER is it correct..?

Comment: start your activity in `PhonecallReceiver` case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK